# Is it possible to find plaintext from ciphertext if (n) and (a) are known for RSA?

Tags: rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis

I have a couple of questions pertaining to a RSA problem. I need to decipher some ciphertext and find out what the original plaintext was.

Modulus: $n = 2537$ and exponent: $a = 11$

Encrypting function: $E(x) = x^{11} \mod 2537$

Using Fermat's Little Theorem to start, I have successfully encrypted some plaintext and decrypted it, so I do know what the other required numbers in this particular RSA system are, however if initially I am only given $n$ and $a$ can I:

1. Mathematically work out some plaintext, if the ciphertext, $n$, and $a$ are known? If so would I basically step through the encryption process in reverse?
2. If not, what is the best/most effective cryptanalysis method to work out what the original plaintext is, if $n$ is relatively small (2537) and $a$ is relatively small (11)?

**Note:** This is needs to be calculated using the 'maths' behind the system and not a specific computer function.

Answer (score 3):

For small numbers the easiest ways to break RSA are:

1. Brute force the private (decryption) exponent. I.e. find the smallest value $b$ such that $(x^a)^b \mod n = x$ for all $x$.
2. Factorize the modulus ([trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) is simplest and works fine for small numbers), then use the factors to [generate the private exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation).

Assuming you are supposed to use the maths, 2. is probably expected.

Comment: Note that this only applies to properly padded RSA. Textbook RSA has weaknesses a plenty.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, "this" being?

Comment: Your claim that these are the easiest way of breaking RSA.

Comment: @CodesInChaos "for small numbers", but yeah, there are other weaknesses to exploit when the message is unpadded plaintext.

Comment: The plaintext is unpadded. @CodesInChaos What are some other methods that I might want to look into besides factorizing the modulus?

Comment: @user3728778 [Boneh wrote a paper listing most know attacks on RSA](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/abstracts/RSAattack-survey.html)